# Does Heroku Postgres offer logical decoding?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I am interested in migrating a medium sized app to Heroku but one potential roadblock is that a key functionality of our product relies on Postgres’ logical decoding. Is it possible to use logical decoding with Heroku Postgres? If not what would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku Postgres does not currently support logical decoding. Additionally, it does not provide access to the `replication` or `superuser` so there is not a good option for streaming changes out of your Postgres database, aside from Heroku Postgres followers.